# Copy text without including formatting characters that are not actually present

Tags: vim

I have some formatting configured in vim for tabs, trailing spaces and line wrapping:

[image]

I have `set mouse=v`, I copy text by selecting it on the terminal and pasting it into another application. How can I configure vim so those formatting characters are not included into the copied text?

Comment: Have you tried setting up yanking to work with the system clipboard?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Vim plugin to toggle linenumbers, listchars, etc. using a mapping: https://github.com/timakro/vim-copytoggle

Ingo Karkat's answer to use the clipboard feature of Vim is an alternative. I decided against it since debian packages Vim without the feature (the vim-gtk package includes it) and I don't want to set up X11 forwarding everywhere, and I don't want to install X11 libraries on headless servers. Also just selecting text with the mouse is more convenient for me. That though can also work using the clipboard feature by setting `set mouse=a` and `set clipboard=autoselect,autoselectplus`, see `:help 'clipboard'`.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't let Vim handle the mouse, it'll be the terminal that processes the text selection. For the terminal, any application is just driving the cursor and printing characters here and there. It doesn't have any semantic background for the terminal contents; it's just lines and columns of characters.

So, you cannot expect the terminal to be able to detect line wrapping inside Vim. Neither can the terminal discriminate between actual text characters and surrounding visual information (the same applies to statuslines, number and fold columns, etc.)

Therefore, if you want access to the actual text, do the copying through Vim; it has the registers `*` and `+` for the X selection and system clipboard, respectively. For these to work, certain preconditions need to be met. There are plenty of related questions here and elsewhere on the Internet (depending on your OS, terminal, and how and what version of Vim you've installed).

If you really can't get this to work, you can `:write` (parts of) the buffer to a temporary file, and do the copy from there. If you connect to a different host, use Samba, `scp`, or `ftp` to transfer the file. As a last resort, temporarily disable the visual embellishments inside Vim, copy from the terminal, and undo hard wraps in the target application after pasting.